# Is it possible to do right-dragging with SmartNAV dwell clicking software?

Tags: smartnav, dwell-clicker

(Right-dragging = you click the right mouse button while pointing at something, hold down the right mouse button and drag the object somewhere)

[image]

I couldn't find the answer in the [NaturalPoint Dwell Clicking Tutorial](http://www.naturalpoint.com/smartnav/support/dwellclick.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to do right-dragging. You might want to have a look at this [list of dwell clicking software that support right-dragging](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3451/903).